# Minecraft Pocket Edition Realms cross-play with PC or Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

Minecraft noob here and I have several questions regarding pocket edition and realms. I'm interested in purchasing Realms for me and my two kids who know much more about Minecraft than I do but they have never used realms.

1. The oldest plays PC Minecraft but also has an iMac he could use, the youngest uses Pocket Edition on a tablet while I have a Macs. Both of them like Android and I have iPhone. Looking at the purchase page for Realms it's asking me to choose between iOS/Android or Mac/PC. So does this mean we're limited to our options here? My youngest doesn't have the skillset yet to do anything with computers so that would mean the rest of us would be limited to Pocket Edition as well? I'd like to be able to play on the Mac/PC when available and then pick up a phone at some other time on the go and play in the same world. Possible?
2. What is the world size on Pocket Edition Realms? I tried searching for it but can only find info on PC Realms.
3. Can you change the Realm type later? Ie if I do go with Pocket Edition realms can I change it to PC/Mac later on? I'm asking because I'm assuming the answer to #1 above is going to be segregated from PC and mobile realms.

Comment: Do you guys have the same wifi? If you do then there is no point in getting realms... you can just play wifi games. PC and Mac can cross play as long as they are in the same version range. But in realms and wifi, both can not cross play.

Comment: One more thing, if you want to customize things (eg: Add mods, enlarge world size etc) your better of setting up your server which is very easy. Click [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Personal-Minecraft-Server). It also shows you how to make a wifi game.

Comment: I'm buying the realms because the WiFi is really buggy. Sometimes it would take closing and reopening the game for over ten minutes before it would show the worlds. I created Live accounts for everyone and added everyone as friends but the worlds still wouldn't show up in the lists all the time. Sometimes we would close and reopen the game over and over and it would never show us the other person's world and we wouldn't be able to play together that day. It was a pain and seems like there's a lot of kinks there.

Comment: Ok, that's good to hear, I've heard many problems with wifi games. But its good to hear that you are buying realms, yes they have good servers but just be careful. it is pricey!

Comment: Flagging question as too broad because it is asking several distinct questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are currently two version branches of Minecraft:
the "Bedrock Edition" for iOS, Android, Windows 10, PS4, XBOX and Switch,
as well as the Java-written Java Edition for any Windows version, macOS and Linux.

Both are currently in further development.
All Bedrock Edition players can only engage in crossplay with other Bedrock Edition players.
All Java Edition players can only engage in crossplay with other Jave Edition players.

A Minecraft Realms subscription is limited to either the Bedrock or Java branch.
This is because the Java and Bedrock edition are different in enough ways that they can't smoothly interact, and that worlds from one can't be used in the other.

For the Java Edition, a feasible alternative to Realms is setting up a self-hosted server on a computer of your choosing.
Both Editions allow players to open up their game to users in the same LAN, limiting multiplayer to local play.

For both Editions, there are publicly hosted Servers.
Some of these allow Jave-Bedrock crossplay, but that's always implemented by the server owners and can limit the possibilities on that server.

As for Size and other differences, I can't help, but point you here: https://minecraft.net/en-us/realms/faq/

Comment: My oldest is getting a Switch next week so it's interesting that he will be able to play with us on it.

Comment: A better term for "Mobile" might be "Bedrock". Since that is what it has been renamed to.

Comment: Theodore Jameson, no, "Bedrock" is the name of the most recent Update. It's now been renamed to "Minecraft", and "Minecraft has been renamed to "Minecraft Java Edition".

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. They're calling it "Bedrock Edition" and "Java Edition" in almost every official communication. I've updated the answer, @MasterOfTheTiger.